# Device Id through Java?

Tags: java

How can i find the device of my fingerprint reader through the Java programming? Is there any specific method in any specific package?

Comment: What operating system? What kind of device connection?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is impossible with portable Java.

IMO, your best bet is to find some command line tool that runs on your machine that will output the device id.  Then use `java.lang.Runtime.exec(...)` to run the command, and "scrape" the id from the output stream.